# horizontally aligned checkbox with input field?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="reference">Reference</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
        <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
                        
          <div class="form-group">
             <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
           <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Demo is required</div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Now i want to aligned checkbox with input field horizontally. I can't figure out after searching.

Comment: You're going to need to put a new `row` inside your `col-md-12`

Comment: where i wrote checkbox ?

Comment: do you want the Reference label, textbox and radio all to be in one row or do you want 2 columns with the radio lining up with the label of the textbox?

Comment: I've added an answer now with a working example :)

Comment: @Pete not radio button checkbox.

Comment: radio / checkbox not really important, the question is how do you want them to line up?  Actually too pendatic, I'm not wasting my time

Comment: @Pete for the sake of clarity. i cut off 3 input fields. so i want only checkbox to be aligned with these 3 input fields.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an example](https://www.codeply.com/go/tZxdd7lFxI) of how you could do it. I put both input fields in a row, where they occupy half of the row with `<div class="col-md-6">`.

Here is the code

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="reference">Reference</label>
            <div class="row align-middle">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <input class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference" type="text">
                    <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input value="" type="checkbox">Option 1</label>
                    <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Demo is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBzLOR

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="reference">Reference</label>
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
          <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">                  
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
              <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Demo is required
              </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
         </div> <!-- ROW CLOSING TAG -->
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: bro you are aligning with label not with `<input>`.

Comment: @stackOverFlowGeek - I've fixed that now, serves me right for not paying full attention!

Comment: where do you put the row closing tag?

Comment: @stackOverFlowGeek - If this helped you then please mark as correct, thanks.